# Change alternate column names in for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am new to Pandas and would like to learn how to change alternate column names -

I have a dataframe which looks like this -
[image]

I would like to change the column names to be like this -
[image]

Any suggestion which apply a for loop would be helpful as I have 57 column names to change in the desired pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little verbose, but it works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Time', 'Jolt1', 'Jolt2', 'Time', 'Jolt1', 'Jolt2', 'Time', 'Jolt1', 'Jolt2'])
c = 1
length = int(len(df.columns)/3)
my_list = []
for i in range(length):
    my_list.append(['Time', 'Jolt'+str(c), 'Jolt'+str(c + 1)])
    c = c + 1
df.columns = sum(my_list, [])
```